# RouteAware on getbuilder flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

i am trying to use RouteAware on getbuilder in flutter so i can run function again when the stateless widget is visible again from calling

Get.until((route) => Get.currentRoute == \dashboard)

```
class DashBoardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder(
        init: DashBoardController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return CustomStateWidget(
              state: controller.pageState,
              widgetError: Text('widgetError'),
              widgetException: Text('widgetException'),
              widgetLoading: Text('widgetLoading'),
              widgetActive: DashBoardActiveWidget(
                controller: controller,
                // buildContext: context,
              ));
        });
  }
}
```

i am using GetMaterialApp

GetBuilder is extending Statefulwidget so we can implement Routeaware on that

```
class GetBuilder<T extends GetxController> extends StatefulWidget {
  final GetControllerBuilder<T> builder;
  final bool global;
  final Object? id;
  final String? tag;
  final bool autoRemove;
  final bool assignId;
  final Object Function(T value)? filter;
  final void Function(GetBuilderState<T> state)? initState,
      dispose,
      didChangeDependencies;
  final void Function(GetBuilder oldWidget, GetBuilderState<T> state)?
      didUpdateWidget;
  final T? init;

  const GetBuilder({
    Key? key,
    this.init,
    this.global = true,
    required this.builder,
    this.autoRemove = true,
    this.assignId = false,
    this.initState,
    this.filter,
    this.tag,
    this.dispose,
    this.id,
    this.didChangeDependencies,
    this.didUpdateWidget,
  }) : super(key: key);

  // static T of<T extends GetxController>(
  //   BuildContext context, {
  //   bool rebuild = false,
  // }) {
  //   var widget = rebuild
  //       ? context
  //       .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedGetxController<T>>()
  //       : context
  //           .getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<
  //               _InheritedGetxController<T>>()
  //           ?.widget;

  //   if (widget == null) {
  //     throw 'Error: Could not find the correct dependency.';
  //   } else {
  //     return (widget as _InheritedGetxController<T>).model;
  //   }
  // }

  @override
  GetBuilderState<T> createState() => GetBuilderState<T>();
}

class GetBuilderState<T extends GetxController> extends State<GetBuilder<T>>
    with GetStateUpdaterMixin {
  T? controller;
  bool? _isCreator = false;
  VoidCallback? _remove;
  Object? _filter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // _GetBuilderState._currentState = this;
    super.initState();
    widget.initState?.call(this);

    var isRegistered = GetInstance().isRegistered<T>(tag: widget.tag);

    if (widget.global) {
      if (isRegistered) {
        if (GetInstance().isPrepared<T>(tag: widget.tag)) {
          _isCreator = true;
        } else {
          _isCreator = false;
        }
        controller = GetInstance().find<T>(tag: widget.tag);
      } else {
        controller = widget.init;
        _isCreator = true;
        GetInstance().put<T>(controller!, tag: widget.tag);
      }
    } else {
      controller = widget.init;
      _isCreator = true;
      controller?.onStart();
    }

    if (widget.filter != null) {
      _filter = widget.filter!(controller!);
    }

    _subscribeToController();
  }

  /// Register to listen Controller's events.
  /// It gets a reference to the remove() callback, to delete the
  /// setState "link" from the Controller.
  void _subscribeToController() {
    _remove?.call();
    _remove = (widget.id == null)
        ? controller?.addListener(
            _filter != null ? _filterUpdate : getUpdate,
          )
        : controller?.addListenerId(
            widget.id,
            _filter != null ? _filterUpdate : getUpdate,
          );
  }

  void _filterUpdate() {
    var newFilter = widget.filter!(controller!);
    if (newFilter != _filter) {
      _filter = newFilter;
      getUpdate();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    widget.dispose?.call(this);
    if (_isCreator! || widget.assignId) {
      if (widget.autoRemove && GetInstance().isRegistered<T>(tag: widget.tag)) {
        GetInstance().delete<T>(tag: widget.tag);
      }
    }

    _remove?.call();

    controller = null;
    _isCreator = null;
    _remove = null;
    _filter = null;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    widget.didChangeDependencies?.call(this);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(GetBuilder oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget as GetBuilder<T>);
    // to avoid conflicts when modifying a "grouped" id list.
    if (oldWidget.id != widget.id) {
      _subscribeToController();
    }
    widget.didUpdateWidget?.call(oldWidget, this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return _InheritedGetxController<T>(
    //   model: controller,
    //   child: widget.builder(controller),
    // );
    return widget.builder(controller!);
  }
}
```

as i have posted GetBuilder class you can check